# How to overcome browser compatibility using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have the following javascript in one of my .aspx page

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) 
{

    if (typeof evt == 'undefined') 
    {
    evt = window.event;
    }
    if (evt) 
    {
    __doPostBack('', 'MyButtonClick');
    }

}
```

This is getting fired if i am working with IE but not with crome or firefox 4, but working fine in firefox 3.6.3.

Please Help!

Comment: working fine in FF 4.0.1 http://jsfiddle.net/Rx45g/1/ Use FireBug to check for script errors

Answer (score 1):

Use [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com):

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(window).unload(function () {
                alert('bye');
            });
            alert('hi');
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Have you put alerts in to verify that it's firing?  I notice in your code that you're trying to do a postback - I'm guessing that won't work as the page will probably be unloaded before the postback could happen.